# Netbeans C++: Execute a source script before building

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile, environment-variables, development-environment

I would like to `source /opt/something/somescript.com` before running the `Makefile` in the Netbeans environment (v8.2). There seems to be answers about this only for Ant and Java, and not for generic C++.

There are only 2 files to play with in Netbeans:

1. The `Makefile`, which is [useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507810/howto-source-a-script-from-makefile) for this purpose
2. The `configurations.xml` file, which maybe is the way to do this.

However, one looks in that configuration file, and there doesn't seem to be anything about running scripts, and I can't find any manual online that explains what XML tags are available.

So my question is: **How can I configure Netbeans to `source` a shell script before building?**

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming GNU Make)

- The very link you provide that you claim proves that Makefile would be useless actually contains at least one recipe of "sourcing" a script into your build: call out to shell (using the `shell` builtin) to:

  - source your script (redirecting all output to `/dev/null`, probably)
  - call `env` and massage the output to emit `VAR:=VALUE` and `export VAR` for every variable
  - (optional) write the result into a file

  Then, if the result went into a file -- `include` that file; otherwise just `eval` the output of `shell`.
- Another possibility is tweaking the magic `SHELL` variable to source your script before running whatever Make wants it to run.  This might become noticeable if your script is heavy, but probably OK if it just sets some environment variables (I know nothing about Netbeans so can't say).

Here's a sample recipe for the first approach (don't actually indent everything by 4 spaces, that's just me struggling with StackOverflow):

```
    # Somewhere at the beginning of the Makefile
    define emit-sourced-env
      $(shell . $1 > /dev/null && env | sed -e 's/=/:=/' -e 's/^/export /' > $(notdir $1).mk)
    endef
    $(call emit-sourced-env,/opt/something/somescript.com)
    include somescript.com.mk
```

Comment: You're making suggestions that are not in the frame of Netbeans building scheme. I don't understand anything of what you said (sorry) because it all is not possible in Netbeans. All I can do is modify that make file. Would you provide a recipe that would solve the problem in the Makefile, or alternatively provide the recipe to make this work on Netbeans?

Comment: added a working GNU Make sample to the answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use project properties for that:

[image: Netbeans Pop-up]

(This is valid for projects with *existing sources*)

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. Try to source something there and see what happens. It gives an error that `source` doesn't exist.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - the line `/bin/bash -c "source ${HOME}/somescript"` will work (on Unix). Of course, all you can do in this script will be limited by the Unix processes design

Comment: This doesn't preserve the environment for make. Once bash exits, the environment variables go with it.

Comment: Yes, sure. I normally use a bunch of `make` include files to import everything I need into all makefiles I use

Comment: Actually you can't import environment variables through makefiles. Thanks for the effort. Sorry it didn't work out.