# source env variables files inside Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, makefile

so from my local machine I am able to do this:

```
 . env_vars.env
```

and it works fine:

**cat env_vars.env**

```
#!/bin/bash
export abce=def
```

but when I try to reflect same in makefile it returns nothing:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

print-env-vars:
        . env_vars.env
        echo ${abce}
```

I also tried with source env_vars.env inside makefile but output is still the same. Wondering how can I source variables inside the makefile.

Comment: This might help: [How to source a script in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7507810/3776858) and [Sourcing a shell script in Make](https://blog.153.io/2016/04/18/source-a-shell-script-in-make/)

Answer (score 12):

Each line of a `make` recipe is executed by a separate shell, so even if you source the file, the shell that sources it exits before the next line is evaluated. It's equivalent to running the following from your shell:

```
bash -c '. env_vars.env'
bash -c 'echo ${abce}'
```

Put both commands on the same line (or use `\` to split a single logical line across multiple physical lines) so that both are executed in the same shell. The semicolon is necessary so that the shell doesn't see `. env_vars.env echo ${abce}`
as the single command to run.

```
print-env-vars:
        . env_vars.env; \
        echo $${abce}
```

(The double dollar sign ensures that you actually pass a parameter expansion to the shell, rather than `make` trying to expand a `make` variable.)

Comment: the double dollar sign did the trick `$$`. Thanks