# Activate Python virtual environment from Makefile

Tags: powershell, makefile, python-venv

I have the following `Makefile` on a folder on Windows 11.

```
VENV = test
PYTHON = $(VENV)/Scripts/python
PIP = $(VENV)/Scripts/pip
ACTIVATE = $(VENV)/Scripts/activate

run: $(ACTIVATE)
    $(PYTHON) api/app.py

$(ACTIVATE): requirements.txt
    py -m venv $(VENV)
    $(PIP) install -r requirements.txt

deactivate: $(ACTIVATE)
    $(VENV)/deactivate

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rmdir $(VENV) /s /q
    rmdir api\__pycache__ /s /q
```

When I execute `make run` on PowerShell, it suscessfully creates the virtual environment, installs the requirements and runs app.py. However, I have noticed that it is not running in the virtual environment. In other words, it is not activating the environment before running.

The reason why I think it is not running on the virtual environment is because when I stop the app, the command line doesn't show '(test)' on the left, as it would usually do. I have also checked some installed packages to make sure I was not in the virtual environment.

If I did it by hand, I would just type `test\Scripts\activate`. I have tried adding this inside the run command before executing api/app.py, but it doesn't seem to be activating it either. I have also tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099519/makefile-to-activate-python-virtual-environment), i.e. adding `test\Scripts\activate && exec bash` right before executing the app but `exec` is not recognized as a command. Replacing `test\Scripts\activate` by `$(ACTIVATE)` does not work either because it says that `test` is not recognized as a command.

What can I do to make sure that api/app.py is running in the virtual environment?

Comment: I recommend you do not try to activate the environment, but instead call the executables placed in the virtual environment's `Scripts` directory (or `bin` on anything else but Windows). For example: `test/Scripts/python -m pip ...`. -- I do not think that *Makefile* rules such as `activate` and `deactivate` make sense.

Comment: @sinoroc shouldn't then `$(PYTHON) api/app.py` run it in the environment? Since `PYTHON = $(VENV)/Scripts/python` is calling an executable.

Comment: Right... indeed it should. I had not paid attention close enough. But anyway the reason you give for thinking that `$(PYTHON) api/app.py` is not running in the virtual environment does not seem correct at all to me. Indeed I do not think you should expect to see the `(test) ` prefix at the command line prompt after running `make run`, because I do not think that the virtual environment would stay activated after `make run` finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do something like this:

```
VENV = test
PYTHON = $(VENV)/Scripts/python

.PHONY: run
run: $(PYTHON)
    $(PYTHON) api/app.py

$(PYTHON):
    py -m venv $(VENV)
    $(PYTHON) -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rmdir $(VENV) /s /q
    rmdir api/__pycache__ /s /q
```

I do not think it makes sense to have `activate` and `deactivate` rules in a *Makefile* and I do not think it would work even, so I skip them. The [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61100516) you linked in your question is meant for *bash* on *Linux*, I am quite sure it would not work on Windows, and I can not think of a solution that would work on Windows.

Comment: When I run that I get a permission denied error when trying to access `test/Scripts/python.exe`.

Comment: I also wonder why you think 'activate' and 'deactivate' rules don't make sense in a *Makefile*.

Comment: I am surprised by the "*permission denied error*". I do not have Windows to test this. -- *Makefile* rules `activate` and `deactivate` do not make sense because that is not what `make` is for. Maybe there is a way to make it work (on Windows, in Powershell), but I do not know one.

Comment: I am surprised too, since it doesn't throw this error with my version. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When do you get the "permission denied error"? Thinking about it, it could be because `requirements.txt` has been modified after `$(PYTHON)` has been created, so `make` tries to update `$(PYTHON)` and fails. There should be a way to tell `make` to never try to recreate `$(PYTHON)` if it already exists (even if `requirements.txt` is newer).

Comment: Right  after `py -m venv test`, so it may be what you say.

Comment: It should be easy to test. Delete the env, call `make run` a couple of times, check that it works, then modify `requirements.txt` and call `make run` again.

Comment: It seems to be working now. How should I confirm that it is running on the virtual environment?

Comment: I guess `api/app.py` runs in the virtual environment if `api/app.py` can import something that was installed from the `requirements.txt` file. Also in `api/app.py` you can add `import sys; print(sys.executable)` and checks that it displays the path to `test/Scripts/python.exe`.

Comment: Yes, it is priting the path to the env executable, thanks!